# Create Profile Model Before User Import With Laravel Excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I'm Importing  My Users  through Excel using the Laravel Excel Package
I want to create a profile Model  before importing users. How do I do this?
The user table has a 1: 1 relationship with the profile table. This means that each user has one profile

User Table :

```
id  username     password                                                      is-admin           created_at           updated_at    department_id  
 1  4480115617   $2y$10$HUBeOzDlTvaJKmI8d5GXJ.qzbqsDcDooi4WG0BrOAHOE9Ce3HMgC6         1  2021-04-16 10:07:34  2021-06-24 04:51:18               10
52  4480124152   $2y$10$.hOMGBCdcrBNx6UbQ4vAOeInnma6mjnztRxL2k8kpV/vK2dEWrj8O         0  2021-07-08 08:01:07  2021-07-08 08:01:07                1
53  12345678910  $2y$10$5d.FMSRyf/KT8bOtQYaSA.BZMLVEKFgjiXL/pjfHCMXmZ7tbZgnPW         1  2021-07-08 08:02:07  2021-07-08 08:02:07                2
54  4420827661   $2y$10$TE8biYPPHhv7ZdUfmY11sO9.7QXOaqKAyWkOEbgsBxJi2uq2iLFs2         1  2021-07-13 06:50:38  2021-07-13 06:50:38                3
```

Profile Table :

```
id  user_id  avatar_src                 phone         address                   email                     created_at           updated_at  field_id  name        family        father  national_code  

 6        1  users/avatars/default.jpg  0xxxxxxxxxxx  یزد                       aa@asdag.com                  (NULL)  2021-06-24 04:51:18    (NULL)  محمد        غریب                                 
21       52  users/avatars/52.jpg       09134576502   adasdasdasdasdas          mohamm@taho.com  2021-07-08 08:01:08  2021-07-13 06:54:05    (NULL)  محمد        کریمی                                
22       53  users/avatars/default.jpg  09134575052   daasdasd                  asda@yaho.com    2021-07-08 08:02:07  2021-07-08 08:02:07    (NULL)  مسعود       رامینی                               
23       54  users/avatars/default.jpg  09134576502   قلثقلقثقثقثث              reza@yaho.com    2021-07-13 06:50:38  2021-07-13 06:50:38    (NULL)  مهدی        رضایی
```

Comment: You can use the `importing to collection method` in [Excel docs](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/collection.html) to achieve this. This row will contain an array with cell values. Inside the looping row you can create the profile using [The realtionship create method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method) defined in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a custom import class, if not you many want to use a custom import class by creating a new class called `UsersImport` in `app/Imports`defined in the [docs](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/collection.html).

UsersImport.php

```php
namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;

class UsersImport implements ToCollection
{
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) 
        {
            // We are creating an instance to use it to create the profile
            $user = User::create([
                'username' => $row[0], //or name of the col with $row['username']
                'password' => $row[1],
                'is-admin' => $row[2],
                'department_id' => $row[3]
            ]);

            // create the profile using $user and one-to-one relationship
            // assuming your relationship is profile() defined in User Model
            $user->profile()->create([
               'avatar_src' => $row['avatar_src'],
               'phone' => $row['phone'],              
               //... your other columns
            ]);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Next call your method  in Database Seeder  with  `Excel::import(new UsersImport, storage_path('Pathtolfile.xlsx'));`